# SharePoint 2013 and SOAP UI

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest

Disclaimer: I have no clue what I am doing with this software. Feel free to correct/advise on anything I am doing wrong.

I am trying to delete a list using SOAP UI. I can **get** a list and see all its properties as xml without issues. However, when I am trying to delete it, I get 403: Forbidden:
[image]

I think it has something to do with X-RequestDigest, but not sure how to pull it correctly or transfer from one request to another. I'd appreciate screenshots and/or idiot-proof explanation.

For the record: I can delete the list from UI, Powershell or Powershell with REST. It is not a SharePoint issue.

Answer (score 1):

call into the /_vti_bin/sites.asmx and use the GetUpdatedFormDigest method